# Can't Seem to Removing Unecessary Audio Devices

Tags: macos, audio, audio-output

I have a few audio devices that I am always having to filter through when I am pushing audio to, for example, my HomePod. I've gone into my HAL folder and removed all that I think were no longer necessary, but I am still unable to remove some of the other devices; like the monitors, which I never use for audio because to my knowledge they don't have speakers.

Here's an image:

[image]

I have also tried following [this question's top answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285311/how-to-stop-sound-output-switching-to-a-monitor-when-it-gets-plugged-in) without any luck; the HomePod just sort of doesn't appear anymore?

SOS! Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U2718Q-HDMI-audio-quality/td-p/5916928, that monitor can pass audio through it, so I guess the Mac does treat it like an output device.  Some of the others seem mostly like ATV/HomePod devices, and I don't think you can remove them.  The microphone is a strange one to show up, for sure.  You could uninstall Soundflower, but since you have a mic, I'm guessing you do some audio recording/mixing and need it. I'm afraid there might not be a way to trim the list without removing the actual devices.  I'll watch & see tho cuz it's a good question!

Comment: @jimtut Ah, wow, I sit corrected! After some more searching, it looks like this maybe isn't possible because I have a DP > mac and as you said, the monitor is broadcasting those i/os. I will follow up if I ever come across a fix, though!